# 'unable to simultaneously satisfy contraints' error on AVPlayer

Tags: xcode, runtime-error, avplayerviewcontroller

How can I fix the "Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints" on my AVPlayer Controller? There are no constraints on the view (The AVPlayer added to the storyboard). It is a segue from a map annotation button - and the AVplayer segue is added in the storyboard and named 'showChosenMovie'.

I have also added 'self.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;

```
 func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
        if (segue.identifier == "addNewEntry") {

        let controller = segue.destinationViewController as! AddNewEntryController

        let specimenAnnotation = sender as! SpecimenAnnotation
        controller.selectedAnnotation = specimenAnnotation
    }
```

else if (segue.identifier == "showChosenMovie") {

```
        let destination = segue.destinationViewController as!
        AVPlayerViewController
        self.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

the console notes:

```
"<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7fcc26abc8a0 h=-&- v=-&- _UIBackdropContentView:0x7fcc278c9890.width == _UIBackdropView:0x7fcc278c82b0.width>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fcc26ca2ee0 H:|-(0)-[UIView:0x7fcc278c9520]   (Names: '|':_UIBackdropContentView:0x7fcc278c9890 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fcc26ca2f30 H:[UIView:0x7fcc278c9520]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':_UIBackdropContentView:0x7fcc278c9890 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fcc26ca2c20 H:|-(0)-[_UIBackdropView:0x7fcc278c82b0]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7fcc278c8140 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fcc26ca2c70 H:[_UIBackdropView:0x7fcc278c82b0]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7fcc278c8140 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fcc26ca28e0 H:|-(0)-[UIView:0x7fcc278c8140]   (Names: '|':AVAlphaUpdatingView:0x7fcc278c7b80 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fcc26ca2930 H:[UIView:0x7fcc278c8140]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':AVAlphaUpdatingView:0x7fcc278c7b80 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fcc26cd81f0 H:|-(14)-[AVButton:0x7fcc278ca160](LTR)   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7fcc278c9520 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fcc26cd8a00 AVButton:0x7fcc26cca550.right == AVButton:0x7fcc26c05740.left - 10>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fcc26cd8910 AVButton:0x7fcc26c05740.right == AVButton:0x7fcc26f83140.left - 10>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fcc26cd8b70 AVButton:0x7fcc26f83140.right == UIView:0x7fcc278c9520.right - 14>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fcc26cd8e70 H:[AVButton:0x7fcc278ca160]-(>=15)-[AVLoadingIndicatorView:0x7fcc26a91ad0](LTR)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fcc26cd8ec0 AVLoadingIndicatorView:0x7fcc26a91ad0.right <= AVButton:0x7fcc26cca550.left - 15>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fcc26abe730 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' H:[AVAlphaUpdatingView:0x7fcc278c7b80(0)]>"
 )

 Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
 <NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fcc26cd8e70 H:[AVButton:0x7fcc278ca160]-(>=15)-        [AVLoadingIndicatorView:0x7fcc26a91ad0](LTR)>
```